# proper way to manage images and static files nginx

Tags: image, nginx

I'm a new coming to nginx service, I misunderstand how nginx manage the files to do show.

Let's say an example. In my web application I have statics file with this path:

```
---public
   | -- js
   | -- img
   | -- css
```

For invoke this kind of static files it just need to digit the current url: `www.mysite.com/js/some.js` or `www.mysite.com/img/myimg.jpg` that's fine it will show up.

But now let's say I have a script on my php files that use a different url to get a image from `public/img` folder using example `www.mywebsite.com/20/10/29/myimg.jpg`

if I add this code to my configuration in nginx, it will get correctly all files to serve to my application giving of course **a real path of the file**

```
location ~* \.(jpe?g|gif|png|ico|css|js|html|htm|woff|svg|ttf)$ {
                  access_log off;
                  expires max;
        }
```

Getting the previous example with the url that generate the image, if I use that block of code in nginx and i try to go:

`www.mywebsite.com/20/10/29/myimg.jpg`

The image will displayed correctly because i show it via php, but on the console log the image get a **404** because nginx go to search for the file with extension **jpg** on `public/20/10/29/myimg.jpg` even if the file is on the `public/img` folder it make sense.

My question is, some one can explain to me how nginx logic has been created for serve static files and files via dynamic url?

Comment: Please, use slash (`/`), not backslash in addresses. It makes me crazy to read `www.mysite.com\js\some.js` and try to guess what do you mean.

Comment: Yes sorry I wrote too many namespaces that's why i fixed that. Anyway thanks for your time.

Comment: “But now let's say I have a script on my php files that use a different url to get a image from public/img” what for? Why it can't use normal static path to file?

Comment: Because example I resize the image with a giving segment of my url by php.

Comment: So actually you have two types of images: static images in `/img/` directory and dynamic images generated by php. Am I right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51740/discussion-between-alexey-ten-and-fabrizio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proper way is to get rid of awful block `location ~* (...)` and use simple prefix locations.

```
location /img/ {
    access_log off;
    expires max;
}
location /js/ {
    access_log off;
    expires max;
}
location /css/ {
    access_log off;
    expires max;
}
```